# Passing context-bound hooks into helper methods in react.js typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have reactjs app set up with typescript.

The components are essentially functions that return `tsx`.

Now to keep things shorter I try to move as much of API-related work out of my component to a simple `.ts` files NEXT to my components (which I call `helpers`) as otherwise the component can easily become a few hundreds of lines since all the template layout code is in the same file.

However, when I use hooks such as `useState` (or similarly with react), `useTranslation` and other context-bound hooks from third-party libraries, I end up writing lengthy argument lists in my helper methods.

Is there any way to pass the instance of the component to the helper such that it's hooks would be available?

My goal is to try to separate JS as much as possible from TSX, basically.

Sample simplified component:

```
import { useEffect, useState, Fragment, useCallback, ChangeEvent, useMemo } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

import { someMethod } from './ComponentHelper';

const Component = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation(["translation", "signups"]);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [something, setSomething] = useState<string[]>();
    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        someMethod('value', () => something, setSomething, () => total, setTotal, () => loading, setLoading, t);
    }, []);

    return (<div>Whatever</div>);
};

export default Component;
```

Sample `ComponentHelper`

```
import { SetStateAction, Dispatch } from 'react';
import { TFunction } from 'react-i18next';

import { someHelperGetMethod } from '../../components/Helpers/ApiHelper';
import { showErrorToast } from '../../components/Helpers/SomeAlertHelper'

import { ApiResponse } from '../../components/Helpers/ApiResponse';
import { SomeModel } from './SomeModel';

// This list of arguments is rather ungodly :/
const someMethod = async function (value: string,
    somethingsAccessor: () => string[],
    setSomething: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[] | undefined>>,
    totalAccessor: () => number,
    setTotal: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number | undefined>>,
    loadingAccessor: () => boolean,
    setLoading: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean | undefined>>,
    translation: TFunction<("translation" | "component")[], undefined>) {
    try {
        if (loadingAccessor()) {
            return;
        }

        setLoading(true);
        let response = await someHelperGetMethod<SomeModel>('api/getSOmething', {
            params: value + somethingsAccessor()[0]
        });

        setSomething(response.data);
        setTotal(totalAccessor() + response.data.length);

        if ('success' in response.data) {
            let resp = response.data as ApiResponse;
            showErrorToast(resp.message ?? translation('component:get_error'));
            return;
        }
    } catch (er) {
        showErrorToast(translation('component:get_error'));
    } finally {
        setLoading(false);
    }
};

export { someMethod };
```